# perl retrieving page details after mechanize::POST

Tags: perl, http-post, www-mechanize, lwp-useragent

I am trying to gather data from a website. Some anti-patterns make looking finding the right form objects difficult but I have this solved. I am using a post method to get around some javascript acting as a wrapper to submit the form. My problem seems to be in getting the results from the mechanize->post method.

Here's a shortened version of my code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Tree;
use LWP::Simple;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use Data::Dumper;
$| = 1;

my $site_url = "http://someURL"; 
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
foreach my $number (@numbers) 
{
    my $content = get($site_url);
       $mech->get ($site_url);

    my $tree = HTML::Tree->new();

    $tree->parse($content);

    my ($title) = $tree->look_down( '_tag' , 'a' );
    my $atag = "";
    my $atag1 = "";
    foreach $atag ( $tree->look_down( _tag => q{a}, 'class' => 'button', 'title' => 'SEARCH'     )  ) 
    {
        print "Tag is ", $atag->attr('id'), "\n";
        $atag1 = Dumper $atag->attr('id');
    }

# Enter permit number in "Number" search field
    my @forms = $mech->forms;
    my @fields = ();
    foreach my $form (@forms)
    {
        @fields = $form->param;
    }
    my ($name, $fnumber) = $fields[2];
    print "field name and number is $name\n";
    $mech->field( $name, $number, $fnumber );
    print "field $name populated with search data $number\n" if $mech->success();

    $mech->post($site_url , 
    [
       '$atag1' => $number,
       'internal.wdk.wdkCommand' => $atag1,
    ]) ;

print $mech->content; # I think this is where the problem is.
```

}

The data I get from my final print statement is the data from teh original URL not the page the POST command should take me to. What have I done wrong?

Many Thanks

**Update**

I don't have Firefox installed so I'm avoiding [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) intentionally.

Comment: try: `$mech->response->content;` or `$mech->response->decoded_content;`

Comment: Thanks jm666.
I get a response back from $mech->content; $mech->response->content; and $mech->response->decoded_content; however they are all for the start page - not the page the POST command should have taken me to.

Comment: There isn't anything blatantly wrong with your code, so I suspect that the problem is going to be specific to the site that you're trying to mechanize.  Therefore, it's highly unlikely that anyone is going to be able to help you with the information that you've provided.

Comment: Thanks Miller - Could it be that the GET and POST commands are running on separate pages meaning that the variables I'm looking up are not valid in the POST command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was excluding some required hidden fields from my POST command.