# WWW:Mechanize GET and POST

Tags: perl, post, get, www-mechanize

In Perl [`WWW:Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3aMechanize) would a

```
$mech->get($url)
```

and a

```
$mech->post($url, [ 'field' => "$var"]);
```

command run on the same or separate instances of a page?

I'm looking up values of form/field IDs and using them to generate the POST command, but it's working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. Every request is independent of any other, so there are no *"instances"* of a page.

It is possible to create sessions by tying requests together using cookies, but from what you've told us that is irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks Borodin, That confirms it for me then.

Comment: Actually Cookies might be relevant. 
Here's what I'm trying to do. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650201/perl-retrieving-page-details-after-mechanizepost
Would cookies be my solution?